# How to receive single message from the queue in RabbitMQ using C#

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I would like to know how I can receive only one message at a time
this is basic code for that

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
var connection = factory.CreateConnection()
var channel = connection.CreateModel()
channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);
var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

BasicDeliverEventArgs ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
var body = ea.Body;
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
Response.Write(message + " Received.");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want wait for 1 message, then keep using `channel.BasicConsume`, but leave consumer method after single message.

If you just get 1 message (if at least 1 exists in queue) then `channel.BasicGet`

```
var data = channel.BasicGet(queueName, true);
```

P.S.:

There are nice example on [CloudAMQP with .NET: Getting started](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/dotnet.html) page.

Answer (score 5):

Complementing the last message if you need the text from the message you need to convert:

```
var data = channel.BasicGet(QueueName, true);
var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.Body);
```

Answer (score -1):

For other languages if you get an error using the `channel.BasicGet` method you can use `channel.get` method of the library
This was the case with me when i was trying to achieve this using Node.Js

my Node.Js code :

```
const open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://admin:password@172.17.0.1:5672?heartbeat:30')
open
  .then(conn => conn.createChannel())
  .then(async channel => {
    console.log('channel created')
    const msg = await channel.get('myQueue')
    if (msg) {
      console.log(msg.content.toString())
      channel.ack(msg)
    }
  })
  .catch(console.warn)
```